# Issue loading Mvc 4 view in Iframe? Not displaying the model properties in IFrame

Tags: iframe, asp.net-mvc-4, mime-types, mime-message

I have this following requirement. Need to display the html Body of the Mime message in IFrame

**View**

```
<iframe id="myIframe1" src="http://localhost:23245/Home/GetMimeMessageContent?FilePath=D \MimeFiles/htmlBody-small1.eml&PartName=HtmlBody" style="width:600px;height:600px;" >
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetMimeMessageContent(string filePath,string partName)
    {
        var mimeModel = BuildMimeModel(filePath, partName);
        MimeHeaderModel mimeHeadermodel = new MimeHeaderModel();
        mimeHeadermodel.FromAddress = mimeHeadermodel.ToAddress = mimeHeadermodel.Subject = string.Empty;
        mimeModel.MimeHeader = mimeHeadermodel;
        return View("MailDetailsView", mimeModel.MimeBody.HtmlBody);
    }
```

it's not showing the HtmlBody in the Iframe. But Its calling the controller. I dont know what I am missing.

Comment: have you tried to just use @Html.RenderAction() inside of an iframe tag

Comment: I tried with @Html.RenderAction(), But I got the error message " CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence"                                                                                      <iframe id="myIframe2" src='@Html.RenderAction("GetMimeMessageContent1", "Home", new {filePath = 'http://localhost:23245/Home/GetMimeMessageContent?FilePath=\MimeFiles/htmlBody-small1.eml', partName = 'HtmlBody'})'
            style="width:600px;height:600px;"></iframe>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if your using jquery or not, but:

```
$(function() {
var $frame = $('<iframe style="width:200px; height:100px;">');
$('body').html( $frame );
setTimeout( function() {

            $.ajax(
               url="/Home/GetMimeMessageType/small1.eml/HtmlBody",
               type:'GET',
               success: function(data){
                  var doc = $frame[0].contentWindow.document;
          var $body = $('body',doc);
          $body.html(data);
               }
            );

},1 );
 });
```

I have not tested the above code, but this should work fine.    A few things to note:

You will need to create a custom Route to map this to your controller:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx

You will also need to change the javascript $('body').html()   to be the ID of a div as a placeholder

also you will notice i have no path, if this never changes, you should add the path to your code  or you can use formcollection and change the jquery ajax to a post, and set the variables and values there.

Your content will then up up in an iframe.

Forget the whole html.renderaction,  this solution gives you a little more scope